# Need suggestion for sqlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

As I'm very very new to sqlite, I need to understand something. How can I store my table name in a variable and use in sqlite query? I'm currently using the existing code but I tried to modifiy the code as mentioned under modified code. Am I doing it right?

**Existing code**

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user_db', [], function (tx, results)
```

**Modified code**

```
var table_name = 'user_db';
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+table_name+"'", [], function (tx, results)
```

Comment: So what is your question? You've not explained what it  is you need to understand, or asked any question at all. *Need suggestion for sqlite* is not a question, and neither is *I need to understand something*. What **specifically** can we help you understand?

Comment: Sorry for that I'll edit.

Comment: Would you like to add a tag for the programming language you are using?

Comment: @Yunnosch angularjs

Comment: You've got an extra set of quotes, but it's mostly right: `'SELECT * FROM '+table_name` - at this point just make the whole sql statement a var - `var sqlString = SELECT * FROM '+table_name` - then do `transaction.executeSql(sqlString, [], function (tx, results)`

Comment: @tymeJV But I have multiple different queries for this table name so I was looking to store the table name in a variable and use it wherever necessary.

Comment: @SubrataBanerjee - Gotcha - then yeah, your code is fine. You dont need that last quote concatenation tho, just: `'SELECT * FROM ' + table_name`

Comment: You might want quotes around the table name, if it is strange, e.g. containing whitespace. In that case you do however need the same quite before the table name, too. @tymeJV I think you can create an answer. I could, too, but it would be misleading to have an answered angularjs question in my profile.

Comment: @Yunnosch - Maybe this is how you get your Angular start :) - and good point about the spaces - didnt think of that. Not sure the question even needs an answer - OP's first attempt was fine minus the quotes - can probably just leave it at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Compiling an answer from comments, most of the know how is by tymeJV.)

Your own code, just without the quote only at the end, should do the trick.

```
var table_name = 'user_db';
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+table_name, [], function (tx, results)
```

You might want the alternative, with quotes on both sides of the variable, it is for cases of "strange" strings in the variable, e.g. containing white space.

```
var table_name = 'user_db';
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+"'"+table_name+"'", [], function (tx, results)
```

Comment: @tymeJV I think Q/A pairs (even without any voting) are better then Q/comment pairs. Let me know if I stumbled somewhere over the angularjs syntax.